# How to proof this linear congruent transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, isometry

First of all I would like to thank you for taking a closer look at the following problem, which unfortunately I have been struggling to solve for days:

> Let $W$ be a n-dimensional Euclidean vector space and let $f \in \text{End}(W)$ such that $(\det(f))^2 = 1$ holds. 
> Also assume
> $||f(w)|| \leq 1$ holds for all $ w \in W $ with $||w|| \leq 1$.
>
> Prove that $f$ is a linear congruent transformation.

---

Since a linear congruent transformation is distance-preserving, I know that one needs to show: $\quad ||f(w)|| = ||w|| \quad (\forall w \in W)$

I've tried many ways to construct an orthonormal basis for $W$ such that I get a mapping matrix of $f$ with respect to that basis, but unfortunately I've been unsuccessful.

I'm deeply grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Hint: prove the inequality $|\det(v_1, \dots, v_n)| \leq \|v_1\| \cdot \dots \cdot \|v_n\|$, and show that equality holds if and only if the $v_i$ are mutually orthogonal. Here, the $v_i$ are vectors and the first expression denotes the determinant of the matrix with columns $v_1, \dots, v_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. Excuse me, but could you elaborate a bit more on how I should proceed? I still don't see myself understanding the purpose of the inequality for the proof.

Comment: Apply the inequality in the case where the $v_i$ are the columns of the matrix of $f$. This means that $v_i = f(e_i)$, where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard basis vector. Then use what you know about the determinant of this matrix and the length of each $v_i$.

Comment: @CJDowd unfortunately i wasn't succesfull on finding a nice proof. Can you elaborate your procedure a little bit more please?

Comment: The determinant of $f$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $f$ (up to algebraic multiplicity). But because $\|f(w)\| \le 1$ for all $w$ with $\|w\| =1$. $f$ can only have eigenvalues between $-1$ and $1$. But the only way a product of positive numbers $\le 1$ can be $1$ is if all the numbers were $1$. So every eigenvalue of $f$ has absolute value $1$.